# With respect to client side security, does CORS do anything other than subvert same-origin-policy?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy, cors

(and if not, does it actually improve client side security?)

I'm thinking of the case where a script from server X uses XHR to obtain and run untrusted code from server Y (which supports CORS).

(obviously evaluating untrusted code is bad™)

Comment: Scripts themselves are not subject to cross-domain restrictions.  For example, a script from domain X can include a script from domain Y, and the code will execute. This can be done with a regular script tag, with no CORS.

Comment: i am aware of this, i don't think it helps to answer the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not use CORS to improve security at all. I use CORS to access a known webservice on a different domain which I would not be allowed to access without CORS. Nothing to do with improving security in my opinion, but to allow data from one domain to be entrusted to another.

Comment: yes this is what i assumed, but it's been bandied about as some kind of security improvement so I got the wrong idea, thanks. So same-origin-policy is more or less redundant thanks to CORS?

Comment: CORS is for you and your data server to be able to communicate. Same Origin policy still applies to any server not implementing CORS. I guess what you mean is that the bad guys can implement CORS with a domain of * that would allow any domain to get their data...

Answer (score 6):

CORS isn't about *hardening* security, it's about *weakening* it (but only under certain conditions with permission from the server).

If you want to access something from another server in an AJAX request, without CORS, you aren't allowed due to "security" (same origin policy), and that is the end of it*. With CORS, the other server can give permission to reduce that security barrier.

<sub>* Except for hacks like JSONP, but that also requires permission from the server</sub>

Comment: are you answering yes or no to my original question?

Comment: @adam77 The answer to your original question is CORS does not do anything related to client side security, at least as far as I understand that phrase. Same Origin Policy prevents trivial browser based denial of service attacks against 3rd party services. CORS allows a third party server to notify a browser that it doesn't need that protection.

Answer (score 1):

CORS subverts the same-origin policy, but selectively so. For example a bank website domain would not set a CORS header at all (to keep same-origin in full effect) as no JavaScript downloaded from other domains should be making AJAX requests to the bank (or maybe they allow just a partner site they trust).  A CDN would probably set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" as it doesn't care if JavaScript downloaded from another domain is making AJAX requests to the CDN.

Comment: so it's a (selective) weakening of security.

Comment: If the same origin policy stated that you shall never open the door to your apartment then CORS says we can make an exception for the pizza guy.